# Tag suggestions while asking a question on Meta are unreadable on hover

Tags: bug, tags, design, meta

When I hover over a tag to select it, Stack Overflow Meta highlights the tag in the **same** colour as the text in the tag, making my mission to read it *impossible*, while the tag has the cursor over it.

#### Without hover active:

[image: Without hover active.]

#### With `hover` active:

[image: With hover active.]

Opera 38.0.2220.31, Update stream: Stable, on Windows 10 64-bit

Comment: Can repro on Firefox ESR 45.1.1

Comment: Also repro on Chrome latest. Looks like it's not a browser-dependent problem.

Comment: I can repro on Safari 9.1/OS X 10.11.4

Comment: Also, the background color for quoted text and tags is also the same value.  So quoting something that has a `[meta-tag:tag]` in it is really weird.  [image](http://i.imgur.com/NHktzkB.png)

Comment: Is that just for new questions or also for editing resp. normal reading? Can't reproduce with rekonq/webkit for the latter two (inline and for full edit). Maybe it **is** a matter of the browser settings?

Comment: @Olaf we were able to reproduce it several hours ago, not anymore. So probably got fixed in the inbetween.

Comment: @Braiam: I never posted a question myself, but edited and read. Checked for the latter again right before I posted. But I would have noticed before if I could not read the tag descriptions. (Presuming it is not only for new questions, of course). Anyway if the issue has been solved for you, I'm fine, as it still seems to work for me, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason this color, #242729, is set as the `background-color` for several conspicuous elements in all.css:

```css
.tag-suggestions>div:focus {
    background-color:#242729
}
.tag-suggestions>div:focus .more-info {
    background-color:#242729
}
.tag-suggestions>div:hover {
    background-color:#242729
}
.tag-suggestions>div:hover .more-info {
    background-color:#242729
}
```

As well as:

```css
.suggestionList .-list>.-item:hover,.suggestionList .-list>.-item._hover {
    background-color:#242729
}

input[type="submit"]:hover,input[type="button"]:hover,button:hover,.button:hover,a.button:hover,a.button:visited:hover,.btn:hover,input[type="submit"]:focus,input[type="button"]:focus,button:focus,.button:focus,a.button:focus,a.button:visited:focus,.btn:focus {
    background-color:#242729; /*other properties omitted*/
}

.ac_over {
    background-color:#242729 /*other properties omitted*/
}
```

Though to be fair, you shouldn't *need* to read it while hovering over it; you can read it just fine without hovering.

Comment: But, I use the pointer to follow where I'm reading!

Comment: @Braiam While I agree that this is a bug and should be fixed, if you do have a reading deficiency, you can use your finger instead of the cursor to keep your place until it is fixed.

Comment: You will get my screen dirty :/

Comment: @Braiam I don't suggest you actually *touch* the screen... what a horrific thought D-: Screen-touchers are quite evil.